# Laravel: Issues with ServiceProvider | Error: Class '...ServiceProvider' not found in bootstrap/compiled.php on line #

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have been working on the same app for a little bit now, and I am moving it over to Laravel. This is not only my first experience with Laravel, but my first time using a PHP framework. It is awesome so far.

I have run into a problem in my testing, I am getting an error: `Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'my-app/Repositories/RepositoryServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 4259`

I am wondering what causes this error and how I can fix it . It gives me the direct line that is problematic. But I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I have tried a number of solutions including

```
composer install
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

and others as well.

I have also attempted deleting the `compiled.php` file all together, but then it trips the same error on a different file. What is it causing this error, and how can I go about debugging it?

This is my **RepositoryServiceProvider.php** file that is being problematic:

```
<?php namespace my-app\Repositories;

use Invite;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use my-app\Repositories\Invite\EloquentInviteRepository;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

 /**
   * Register the Invite Repository
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function registerInviteRepository()
  {
    $this->app->bind('my-app\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository', function($app)
  {
      return new EloquentInviteRepository( new Invite );
  });
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "way/generators": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

This is the specific line in **compiled.php** that is giving the issue:

```
{
    return new $provider($app);
}
```

You guys have been a huge resource in the past.

I've experienced almost 24 hours of coding downtime because of this probably simple problem, and I've restored and rebuilt twice, only getting back to this error.

Thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: Can you paste your `composer.json` file as well?

Comment: @lowerends It's been added! Thanks for the response! I've tried with the directory `'app/my-app'` under `autoload` as well. Unless I've done it wrong.

Comment: Try adding The path to the file in your classmap in composer.json

Comment: @Kao Thanks for the suggestion. Still the same error though even after that update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried registering your provider under 'providers' array of /app/cofig/app.php then do a composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: This is consistently what breaks the app. The second I register the Service Provider in app.php the error starts generating. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It actually turned out being this. I was registering the directory path, oblivious to the fact that I had to register simply the filename after doing a `dump autoload -o`. Thanks again!